# Jsf Project with Sql Server - Windows Authentication

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jsf, tomcat, windows-authentication

do you know the way i have to configure my web project to be able to connect to sql server with windows authentication? what i need is to use the user credentials to access to the database, i will use

```
Apache tomcat 7
JSF 2.1.2
```

Do tou know if this is posible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I connect to SQL Server using integrated security with the JDBC driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629718/how-can-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-integrated-security-with-the-jdbc-driver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You will need the `sqljdbc_auth.dll`. There's 3 places you can place it:

1. in your `WEB-INF/lib` of the application
2. In your Tomcat's `lib` folder
3. In `C:\windows\system32`. [Possible problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10637585/1362049). The dll is distributed with the JDBC driver of Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

In your connection string, use `integratedSecurity=true;` (example: `jdbc:sqlserver://MyServer;databaseName=MyDatabase;integratedSecurity=true;`)

**Update 1**: found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629718/how-can-i-connect-to-sql-server-using-integrated-security-with-the-jdbc-driver) post on Stackoverflow for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Simon Arsenault , basically I dont need to add any user or pass right? Tomcat will take the windows credentials to access sql server instance?

Comment: Is it going to be for each users? Because that is what i am looking ... the user accessing the web page to be anthenticated... is it posible?

Comment: Found this that helps too [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523865/jdbc-simple-mssql-connection-example-not-working/12524566#12524566)

Comment: It will use the windows credentials of the user running the tomcat process/service.

Comment: Why do you want to use the credentials of the user loggued into your application? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Use different users to connect to the database in order to have more efficiency, but i am thinking not to do that... i guess is not posible

Comment: Why would it be more efficient? And yes, I would suggest that you use a connection pool with the user running Tomcat.